# Grabbing the updated CSS Property value

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to pull the value of a CSS property that was dynamically updated with jQuery? For example, a div could start with 0 opacity. On each hover, the div would have more opacity added to it, so grabbing the opacity through jQuery would grab original opacity on first hover and the new opacity on each additional hover.

In the jsfiddle, I have it working by creating a new data property but I want to pull the updated properties instead. On the example where I grab the Opacity property, you can see that after 2 hovers, the variable no longer updates properly.

(https://jsfiddle.net/nvr6qx3k/4/)

```js
$(".row").on("mouseover", "div", function() {

 var opacity = parseInt($(this).css("opacity")) || 0;
  opacity = opacity + 1;
  $(this).css("opacity", opacity);
  console.log("opacity is " + opacity);
  
  var count = parseInt($(this).data('click')) || 0;
  count = count + 1;
  $(this).data("click", count);
  console.log("count is: " + count);
  
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that opacity is 1.0 at max so if you add 1 to it it will become 2. But 2 set to opacity will be limited and set as 1.0; I tried with incrementing by 0.1  and since your css sets opacity to 0.5 at first hover it returned 0.6 and at second 0.7, then 0.8, 0.9 finally 1.0 and 1.1 which wouldn't go higher as value you set for opacity style is limited to 1.0 (I also changed parseInt to parseFloat so it work with 0.1 increments)

Comment: Wow, that was it! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS opacity values are from 0 to 1.
1 beeing 100%

So opacity = 2 doesn't make sense.

On mouseover, you should add 0.1... And you'd see the effect.
Also... `parseInt()` returns an integer...

So the use of `parseFloat` is better to retreive floating numbers.
;)

```js
var opacity;

$(".row").on("mouseover", "div", function() {

  opacity = parseFloat($(this).css("opacity")) || 0;
  opacity = opacity + 0.1;
  $(this).css("opacity", opacity);
  console.log("opacity is " + opacity);
  
  var count = parseInt($(this).data('click')) || 0;
  count = count + 1;
  $(this).data("click", count);
  console.log("count is: " + count);
  
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you should start to 0.2 opacity because css opacity max value is 1. maybe add 0.2 every mouse over. instead of parstInt use parseFloat because parseInt can just return 0 of (0.5) that's why you can't get the value of current opacity.

check this:

```js
$(".row").on("mouseover", "div", function() {

 var opacity = parseFloat($(this).css("opacity")) || 0;
  opacity = opacity + 0.2;
  $(this).css("opacity", opacity); 
  
  var count = parseFloat($(this).data('click')) || 0;
  count = count + 1;
  $(this).data("click", count);
  console.log("count is: " + count);
  
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```